# PHP: Count stdClass objects within array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have an array with stdClass objects as below. How would I count how many I have under Interviewee_Name?

Tried counting as I would do an array but get an error that I can't becaused of the stdClass Object and then unsure how to proceed from there

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Interviewee_Name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => rn_Interviewee_Name_DIR_27
                            [value] => Janusz Jasinski
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried to do? You should be able to count any array, regardless of what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

This'll get the number of elements under `Interviewee_Name`, but it'll count all elements, not just objects.

```
count($arr[0]->Interviewee_Name)
```

However, if you really only want to get the *objects* in `Interviewee_Name`, you'll need to [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the array to get only the objects, and then count that new array:

```
count(array_filter($arr[0]->Interviewee_Name, function ($el) {
    return (gettype($el) == 'object');
}));
```

The syntax for getting an element from an array looks like `$arr['index']`, but in this case `Interviewee_Name` is a property of an object so you need to use the object syntax: `$obj->prop`

Comment: So if I wanted to get  the value, would I do `$arr[0]->Interviewee_Name[0]->value`?

Comment: @pee2pee What doesn't work, the second block of code to filter non-objects, or your code to get the value?

Comment: Ignore me - using $arr but I changed it to $a :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($formData), True);
```

I added that to before looking to do a count and it worked!

Comment: Yes, the second parameter indicates that `json_decode` will convert `$formData` into an associative array instead of an object, however, this is unnecessary overhead that could be avoided if you simply change how you get `Interviewee_Name`